# Declaring multi-element array within EM_ASM_INT breaks compilation

Tags: emscripten

I'm trying to declare a multi-element array inside an EM_ASM-style macro. This works fine when I just use plain old EM_ASM:

```
EM_ASM({var a = [1,2];});
```

However, doing this within any of the EM_ASM-style macros that return a value seems to confuse the compiler.

For instance:

```
 EM_ASM_INT_V({var a = [1,2]; return 1;});
```

Gives me these errors:

> error: too many arguments provided to function-like macro
>         invocation
>
> test.cc:4:3: note: cannot use initializer list at the beginning of a macro argument
>
> test.cc:4:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'EM_ASM_INT_V'

The same is true for `EM_ASM_INT`, `EM_ASM_DOUBLE`, and `EM_ASM_DOUBLE_V` (regardless of whether I give them the appropriate arguments and returns). If I declare a 1-element array:

```
 EM_ASM_INT_V({var a = [1]; return 1;});
```

everything is fine. This also happens with curly-bracket enclosed Javascript objects - a single element (e.g. `{val1: 1}`) is fine, but any more than that (e.g. `{val1: 1, val2: 2}`) gives me the same error.

My current workaround is individually pushing additional elements to the array:

```
 EM_ASM_INT_V({var a = [1];
               a.push(2); 
               return 1;});
```

This works, but it's pretty clunky.

I checked the Emscripten github page for related issues, but couldn't find any. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug? Anyone have a better workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem has to do with the comma in the macro call.  Commas are ignored inside of parentheses, but not in braces, brackets, or angle brackets, so it splits your first argument into two: `{var a = [1` and `2]; return 1;}`, which is clearly problematic.

I haven't looked at the definition of EM_ASM, but since it's only expecting a single argument, my guess is that if it gets more than one it automatically glues them together with commas.  The other EM_ASM_* macros, however, don't know how many arguments to expect, so they can't do this.

As for a fix, you can usually include extra parentheses.  For your example, you should be able to use:

```
EM_ASM_INT_V({var a = ([1,2]); return 1;});
```

The parentheses won't hurt anything there, but will keep the macro argument glued together properly (sometimes it isn't so easy, but it usually is).

I know fixing this in the preprocessor spec has been a conversation for a long time -- hopefully it will be someday.  It's gotten particularly annoying when including templates in a macro call since there's no easy way to surround everything in parentheses in those cases.

EDIT: I check the EM_ASM definition, and indeed it is a variadic macro that glues the arguments back together.